# Disable "list" leaving only "add new" and "delete"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I have a project that is using SonataMediaBundle, and I am working on the GalleryAdmin page. My goal is to only allow uploads of images, rather than allowing images and videos.

I have set up sonata_media.yml so that inline uploads of new media only allow images. However, if there are existing Media records that contain video -- YouTube records, for instance -- the gallery allows selection of those video items alongside images. This is not the desired behavior.

**How do I change my GalleryAdmin (or other files) so that selection of existing Media records is not possible, and only fresh uploads are allowed?** This would fix the problem.

====

Edit: To clarify, I basically want to remove the "List" button from my Media list view, leaving only "Add new" and "Delete."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **The available options are** section [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/form_types.html#sonata-adminbundle-form-type-modellisttype), you can disable any button.

Edit:

Just extends [this](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/3.x/src/Admin/GalleryHasMediaAdmin.php#L41-L44) and overwrite the formFields and there you need to hide list option for media field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The current MediaAdmin.php class that comes with the bundle does not contain a configureFormFields definition. Am I looking in the wrong place? If not, what would the block I add potentially look like?